# Can't directly have [audio].play() as a jQuery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, callback, html5-audio

Consider this code:

```
var music = $("audio")[0];
//doesn't work
$("#pbutton").click(music.play);
//works
$("#pbutton").click(function(){music.play()});
```

The line that doesn't work returns this error in Firefox:

`TypeError: 'play' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLMediaElement.`

Am I missing something here? Why doesn't this work?

Update: I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvvzsbjb/) for this.

Comment: Is it working okay for you without jQuery, as in using document.getElementById('audio').play()?

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to clarify, so you mean this does not work `("#button").click(function(){document.getElementById('audio').play(); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually pretty simple. [I've updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvvzsbjb/1/) to show it.

```
var x = {
    play: function()
    { 
        console.log(this);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var music = document.getElementById("song");

    $("#play").click(function()
    {
        x.play();
    });

    $("#play").click(x.play);

    $("#pause").click(music.pause);
});
```

Look at the code and your developer console. In the first click handler you call the function **play** of the object **x**. Since it is "normal" invocation, the **this** in the function is the **x object**, which is correct.

As your second click handler you *point* directly to the **x.play** function. But because jQuery maintains the this-context of the function you use as click handler, the **this** in the function is now the play-button.

Now, if something in your play-function uses the **this-variable**, you get errors (because inside your **play** function you assume that **this** is your **x-object**). And that's the reason why you often have to wrap an anonymous function around a parameterless function-calls to make it work.

Comment: I see. Javascript scope is strange. Thanks!