# jQuery Callback .load not working on mobile device

Tags: jquery, callback

This code:

```
$("#sound").load("randomradio.php", function() {
    var r = document.getElementById("radio");
    r.play();
});
```

randomradio.php dynamically creates a `<audio id="radio">`...

and it works fine on my PC webbrowser. Just not on mobile devices and I can't figure out why.

Comment: are you sure that callback is not at all working OR `r.play()` is not working. Try putting `alert(1)` inside callback and check whether you get the alert or not. I guess your callback is getting called but might be issue with audio. Or may be volume is zero by defualt.

Comment: alert works. one step further. r.play seems to not work. at least not in the callback, because I used the .play function somewhere else and it works on the mobile phone

Comment: try alerting `alert($("#radio").length);`. See what you get.

Comment: getting a "1" on alert($("#radio").length);

Comment: ok...so now can you try setting volume like `r.volume = 0.5;` after `r.play();`?

Comment: Works! On mobilephone too! Heard that autoplay on mobilephones is disabled, maybe a callback function with a .play on a load is considered as an "autoplay"?

Comment: I guess on mobile the default volume is 0. So after manually playing the audio with `.play()` you also need to increase the volume programmatically.

Comment: please post your answer and accept it so that other OPs facing the same issue will get benefited in future.

Comment: Sorry what I was saying was, the change of volume works for mobile but the .play still doesn't work. I have the controller (player) on and it just won't work on the mobile phone..

Answer (score 0):

jQuery should work fine on mobile devices.

jQuery mobile is something else entirely, you don't need it. Perhaps the code is breaking when you viewed on a mobile device? Have you tried looking at your javascript errors? You can see error

You can find these errors in the JavaScript Console. For Chrome you can open it in a couple ways:

- Use the keyboard shortcut Command - Option - J (Mac) or Control -Shift -J (Windows/Linux).
- Select View > Developer > JavaScript Console.

Comment: This seems to work. `test_audio_played = false;

$('<audio>').on('play', function() {
    test_audio_played = true;
})[0].play();

setTimeout(function() {
    alert(test_audio_played);
}, 1);`

Comment: strange thing there. works on pc, output for test_audio_played is true and on mobile phone it doesnt play and gives back false.

Comment: @cenkuluisik cloud you clear your mobile browser `cache`?

Comment: I think it wont change anything, because this doesn't work on other phones too.

Comment: @cenkUluisik read this question it may helped you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476999/cant-directly-have-audio-play-as-a-jquery-callback